# как заблокировать отправку почты от некоторых локальных пользователей?

Tags: exim

ситуация:

1. машина, на которой работают несколько сайтов.
2. каждый сайт работает от имени своего локального пользователя (*apache*-вская «фича» *assignuserid*).
3. в качестве *smtp-сервера* используется *exim*.
4. один (или несколько) сайтов «взломали» (или воспользовались какой-то уязвимостью движка) и теперь рассылают спам, то ли напрямую вызывая */usr/sbin/sendmail* (это ссылка на программу */usr/sbin/exim4*), то ли пользуясь какими-то библиотечными функциями (типа *php [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)*).
5. устранить уязвимость (или исправить последствия взлома) «прямо сейчас» невозможно.

как, не отключая «спамящий» сайт(-ы), полностью заблокировать отправку почты для данного локального пользователя(-ей)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. создайте файл, в котором будут храниться имена заблокированных локальных пользователей (имя произвольное, месторасположение — каталог с конфигурацией *exim*, обычно — `/etc/exim4`), по одному на строку:

   ```
   $ cat /etc/exim4/local_user_blacklist
   user1
   user2
   ```
2. в конфигурацию *exim* надо добавить два «куска».

   **если** у вас *debian-основный* дистрибутив и при конфигурировании пакета *exim4-config* вы выбрали разбивку на мелкие файлы, то «кусок 1» можно вставить в файл, например, `/etc/exim4/conf.d/main/99_non_smtp` (местоположения файла — существенно, а имя — произвольное, цифры же определяют порядок включения файла в результирующую конфигурацию в `/var/lib/exim4/config.autogenerated`), а «кусок 2» — в файл, например, `/etc/exim4/conf.d/acl/10_non_smtp`.

   **иначе** — смотрите ниже, куда именно должны быть вставлены «куски».

   1. «кусок 1»:

      ```
      acl_not_smtp = my_acl_not_smtp
      ```

      должен быть вставлен **до** директив, начинающихся со слова `begin`.
   2. «кусок 2»:

      ```
      my_acl_not_smtp:
      discard message = not permitted user "$sender_ident"
      condition = ${lookup{$sender_ident}lsearch{CONFDIR/local_user_blacklist} {yes}{no}}
      accept
      ```

      должен быть вставлен **после** директивы `begin acl`, но **до** следующей директивы, начинающейся со слова `begin`. можно сразу же ниже директивы `begin acl`.

   обратите внимание на переменную `CONFDIR`: если в вашей конфигурации она не определена (как в *debian-основных* дистрибутивах), то подставьте вместо неё абсолютный путь к созданному в первом пункте файлу `local_user_blacklist`.
3. перезапустите *exim*. примерно так:

   ```
   $ sudo service exim4 reload
   ```
4. проверьте, что письма от заблокированного пользователя (*user1*) не уходят:

   ```
   $ echo test | sudo -u user1 mail -s zagolovok komu@nib.ud
   ```

   в логе (обычно — `/var/log/exim4/mainlog`) должно появиться что-нибудь вроде:

   ```
   дата время идентификатор_письма <= user1@vash.host U=user1 P=local S=346
   дата время идентификатор_письма => blackhole (non-SMTP ACL discarded recipients): not permitted user "user1"
   дата время идентификатор_письма Completed
   ```

теперь можно добавлять/удалять блокируемых пользователей в файле `/etc/exim4/local_user_blacklist` без перезапуска *exim*, прямо «на лету».